# Automatically enter in bash shell

Tags: shell, login

I just got an VPS in GoDaddy, and when I connect using ssh, it enter in a simple shell, so I need to type "bash" to enter in bash mode.

Why this happens? I had another VPS in DigitalOcean and it enters in bash shell automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try the command:

> chsh -s /bin/bash

Comment: I just had to add the user:  sudo chsh -s /bin/bash myuser